# Function pointer pointing to functions with different number of arguments

Tags: c, function, pointers

How to handle assignment of the functions to one function pointer, each with different number of parameters ? The problem is that parameters differ in number and type. If possible give an example.

Comment: A function can **only** be called through a function pointer if the pointer type is compatible with the function, i.e. the number/types of the parameters are the same and the return type is the same.

Comment: Is it possible to adapt the function pointer dinamically with the function it is pointing to?

Comment: No, the function pointer would need to be casted to the proper type.

Comment: @dbush So no solution for this problem? Do you have any advice?

Comment: You need to rethink what you are doing.  Function pointers allow you to switch at runtime between different functions with the same signature.  You have to write different calls for the different numbers and types of parameters (and return values) anyway.

Comment: Yes, the signature is problem, thanks.

Comment: If you understand the calling convention used, you can pass a function number as one argument, usually the first or last.  The snag is that, AFAIK, you need assembler to untwist the stack and call the required function:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function pointers can be cast in the same way as the other pointers. You will have a generic function pointer (similar to `void *` for storage types), and use it to hold/pass the address of the function. Before calling the function, you will need to cast it to the correct type.

Here is a working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (*generic_t)(void);
typedef int  (*type2_t)(int);
typedef int  (*type3_t)(int, char *s);


void test1(void) {
    printf("Test 1\n");
}

int test2(int i) {
    printf("Test 2 %i\n",i);
    return i;
}

int test3(int i, char *s) {
    printf("Test 3 %i, %s\n", i, s);
    return i++;
}

int main(void) {
    generic_t f1, f2, f3;
    f1 = &test1;
    f2 = (generic_t)&test2;
    f3 = (generic_t)&test3;

    f1();
    int i = ((type2_t)f2)(10);
    i = ((type3_t)f3)(20,"This is test");
}
```

In addition, you will need to implement a mechanism to recognize what is the type of function that the pointer is pointing to. One approach is to use a `struct` that holds the pointer and the `enum` of the type.

Comment: The `&` on `&test1` and friends is redundant.

Comment: I know that it's redundant, but makes the code more readable. I wanted to add `f1 = (generic_t)&test1` but left it out as it's already obvious.

Comment: I wonder if the C Standard actually makes this defined behavior. There does not seem to be any equivalent to `void *` for function pointers that guarantees roundtrip conversion.

Comment: @chqrlie C11 6.3.2.3p8 allows for a function pointer to be converted to another function pointer and back.  A cast is required, but it is allowed.

Comment: @jordanvrtanoski: You might want to add a reference to the C Standard: C11 **6.3.2.3 Pointers** p8: *A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a function of another type and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. If a converted pointer is used to call a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.*

Comment: @0___________ There's no UB here.  The function pointers are converted to one type, then back to a compatible type before being called.

Comment: @dbush indeed but it makes no sense considering the OP question

Comment: @0___________ If anything it demonstrates that what OP is asking for doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to create a union of different function pointer types:

```
union funptr {
    void (*v)();
    void (*vi)(int);
    void (*vs)(char *);
    int  (*i)();
    int  (*ii)(int);
    int  (*iii)(int, int);
    int  (*is)(char *);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use void pointers to pass reference to the `in` and `out` parameters. Multiple parameters and return values you can wrap in the structs. The return value may return status.

Sometimes it used in low-level device drivers.

```
typedef int func(void *, void *);

func *fptr;

struct s1 
{
    int i;
    char *s;
};

int test1(void *in, void *out) 
{
    printf("Test 1\n");
    return 0;
}

int test2(void *in, void *out) 
{
    int *i = in;
    printf("Test 2 %i\n", *i);
    return *i;
}

int test3(void *in, void *out) 
{
    struct s1 *s = in;
    printf("Test 3 %i, %s\n", s -> i, s -> s);
    return ++s -> i;
}

int main(void) 
{
    fptr = test1;
    fptr(NULL, NULL);
    fptr = test2;
    fptr((int[]){10}, NULL);
    fptr = test3;
    printf("Returned value: %d\n", fptr(&(struct s1){20,"This is test"}, NULL));
}
```

Comment: Yup - that would be my preferred mechanism.

Answer (score -1):

You have to declare a new function pointer type for every different signature that you need to handle.

Comment: But what is a purpose of the function pointer in that situation?

Comment: @Zmax: the purpose of a function pointer is to allow you to change the function called to one of a number of possible functions with the same arguments and return type.  You have to write out a different call for each possible argument list anyway.

Comment: I understand the use, but in this concrete situation, it does not have any purpose, as I am having functions different in return type and number/type of parameters.

Comment: @Zmax But that is not a bad thing, why do you think it is?

Comment: I don't think it is, but in my situation it is, as its rare case that I can group two functions having the same signature, almost I does not have it. In that case I can directly call all of them, without introducing unnecessary function pointers. What I wanted is to switch to the appropriate one during runtime.